# Solving an inequality after simplifying bounds

Tags: inequality, logarithms, contest-math

I am currently working on an olympiad inequality problem, and I am feeling stuck. The problem is this:

Prove the following inequality
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[2017]{2018}}+\frac{1}{2017}(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2018})< 1$$

### This is my attempt to solve:

We have
$$2018^{1/2017}
> 2018^{1/2018} > 2048^{1/2048}
= 2^{11/2048}$$

Using $\frac{1}{k} < \ln k - \ln(k - 1)$ for all $k \ge 2$, we have
$$\frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2018} < \ln(2018) - \ln 2 < \ln 2048 - \ln 2 = 10\ln 2.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$2^{-11/2048}+\frac{1}{2017}(1/2 + 10\ln 2) < 1$$
or
$$\ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{2017}(1/2 + 10\ln 2)\right) + \frac{11}{2048}\ln 2 > 0.$$

---

1. I assumed the inequality $\frac{1}{k} < ln k - ln(k-1)$, and I verified it worked on desmos. But I am not familiar with logs and I don't know how to prove it.
2. Now at the last step is where I am stuck. I don't know how to continue and solve this inequality. Can someone give me some help and tell me how to solve it?

Thanks for help...

Comment: Not sure about $2$ but for $1$ you have $$\ln(k)-\ln(k-1) = \int_{k-1}^{k}\frac{1}{x}\ dx > \int_{k-1}^{k} \frac{1}{k} \ dx = \frac{1}{k} $$

Comment: Why did you copy my solution and said it was your attempt? See: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h3028476_evaluating_an_expression

Answer (score 2):

Not really related to your doubt but a slightly simple way of going about it:

$\frac{1}{2018^{1/2017}} + \frac{1}{2017} (\frac{1}{2} +  \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4}  + ... + \frac{1}{2018}) < 1 \\
 \frac{1}{2018^{1/2017}} + \frac{1}{2017} (\frac{2-1}{2} +  \frac{3-2}{3} + \frac{4-3}{4} + ... + \frac{2018-2017}{2018}) < 1 \\
 \frac{1}{2018^{1/2017}} + 1  - \frac{1}{2017} (\frac{1}{2} +  \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{4} +  ... + \frac{2017}{2018}) < 1 \\
 \frac{1}{2018^{1/2017}}   <\frac{1}{2017} (\frac{1}{2} +  \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{4} + ... + \frac{2017}{2018})  \\$

And this is true using AM-GM inequality

Comment: It is elegant. (+1)